# Jenkins form validation with objects as parameters

Tags: jenkins

I'm building a plugin for Jenkins and I'm trying to validate my form (connection test method). This worked fine when all `@QueryParameter` were Strings.

Now I'm trying to send my form validation method an Object like this:

```
        public FormValidation doTestConnection(
                @QueryParameter("url") final String url,
                @QueryParameter("timeout") final String timeout,
                @QueryParameter("bypassProxy") final boolean bypassProxy,
                @QueryParameter("deployerCredentialsConfig") final CredentialsConfig deployerCredentialsConfig,
                @QueryParameter("resolverCredentialsConfig") final CredentialsConfig resolverCredentialsConfig
        ) throws ServletException {
```

In my global.jelly file I have this:

```
<f:validateButton
        title="${%Test Connection}" progress="${%Testing...}"
                        method="testConnection"
                        with="url,timeout,bypassProxy,deployerCredentialsConfig,resolverCredentialsConfig"/>
```

My `CredentialConfig` class implements `Serializable` but I guess that is not enough becuase I'm getting this when clicking the "Test Connection" button:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to invoke public hudson.util.FormValidation
```

org.jfrog.hudson.MyBuilder$DescriptorImpl.doTestConnection(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean,org.jfrog.hudson.CredentialsConfig,org.jfrog.hudson.CredentialsConfig) throws javax.servlet.ServletException

Jenkins has no good documentation for using objects inside of FormValidation calls.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Jenkins documentation and the code behind <f:validateButton/>, **I believe it's impossible** have objects bind in validation logic.

The docs say (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jelly+form+controls):

> The 'with' attribute specifies the input fields sent to the server for
>   the validation. They are matched against the field attribute or the
>   name attribute of other input controls. The values of the nearest
>   input fields above the  are sent to the server, so
>   this means the button has to come after the input fields. Multiple
>   fields can be specified by using ','.

The code simply gets fields by the names - there is no "object assembly" (I believe it's only done during actual config submission).

https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/96ec7a267e0efba2ec99590c871db0940e35920f/war/src/main/webapp/scripts/hudson-behavior.js#L2856

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into a similar problem. Looking at the code, it seems stapler tries to convert your parameter to the type you provided in the `doCheck` function declaration.

```
    class HandlerImpl extends AnnotationHandler<QueryParameter> {
    public Object parse(StaplerRequest request, QueryParameter a, Class type, String parameterName) throws ServletException {
        String name = a.value();
        if(name.length()==0)    name=parameterName;
        if(name==null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter name unavailable neither in the code nor in annotation");

        String value = request.getParameter(name);
        if(a.required() && value==null)
            throw new ServletException("Required Query parameter "+name+" is missing");
        if(a.fixEmpty() && value!=null && value.length()==0)
            value = null;
        return convert(type,value); // <--- HERE
    }
}
```

As a workaround, I changed the type to boolean, like so:

```
    public FormValidation doTestConnection(
            @QueryParameter("url") final String url,
            @QueryParameter("timeout") final String timeout,
            @QueryParameter("bypassProxy") final boolean bypassProxy,
            @QueryParameter("deployerCredentialsConfig") final boolean deployerCredentialsConfig,
            @QueryParameter("resolverCredentialsConfig") final boolean resolverCredentialsConfig
    ) throws ServletException {
```

This allows me to at least check if the variable is set. It might not be enough for your use case, though.